# Set system property from javadoc command line

Tags: java, command-line, javadoc

Is there similar/same arguments like `-D<name>=<value>` for `javadoc` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It looks like `-J` should work](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#CHDGDEEE)

ie

```
javadoc -J-Dname=value
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. I'll mark as answer when I can